WP Multisite: The plugin 0 has been deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist
Something happened with our Multisite installation that broke everything. So in an attempt to find the problem we deleted all the plugins and themes it showed the warning "The plugin 0 has been deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist."
Then we tried to upload all the plugins and themes back again making sure all were clean (and on their most recent versions) and when we try to network activate any plugin it gives us a Fatal error with the same messaage.
The debug.log file shows the following:
[28-Aug-2024 16:48:21 UTC] Cron reschedule event error for hook: action_scheduler_run_queue, Error code: invalid_schedule, Error message: Event schedule does not exist., Data: {"schedule":"every_minute","args":["WP Cron"],"interval":60}
[28-Aug-2024 17:28:51 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php:708
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-admin/plugins.php(60): activate_plugin()
#1 /var/www/html/wp-admin/network/plugins.php(13): require('...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php on line 708

We already uploaded clean wordpress folders and files except for wp-content and wp-config.php, hoping that fixed the problem, but nothing. We also checked and deleted the meta_value of the active_plugins table of each site and of the active_sitewide_plugins table. But it still the same and can't find the origin of the problem.

"So in an attempt to find the problem we deleted all the plugins" - that is a fairly dangerous option, especially in an MS install. Are you able to just restore from a known good backup?

We could, but we'd lost like a ton of information that has been fed through the last month. 2 of the 3 sites are LMS, so all the work done by more than 2,000 students would be lost. So that's a bad option.

Something happened with our Multisite installation that broke everything - What was the error when this happened? What does "broke everything" mean? It seems you took a ton of drastic measures before trying small fixes. We can't help you with what was provided, since anything could be the issue. Did you take a backup of the database before you deleted everything?

We do have a backup of the DB. Here's what happened...
On friday we've been notified that both LMS were too slow, so we went on and followed a normal maintenance procedure. Updated all plugins and themes, checked the server configuration and dropped the caches. We tested everything again and it still was slow, so we went on to deactivate all plugins and activate them one by one. When we reached the Litespeed plugin there began to appear some PHP warnings about other plugins that were not activated yet. When we tried to activate them the Fatal error I mentioned here start to appear.

@JonathanKleemann, we've all been there, so I hope I don't sound like I'm hammering you. Is it one month or three days that'd you lose? Basically, is your known good backup fairly old still? And as part of your normal maintenance, did you guys take a backup before that that you could at least restore to? I'm not trying to get you to "good", I'm just trying to get you to "not broken", which still might be slow.

We have a recent DB backup which is the one we're using right now. The one before that is from a month ago, so....

So we moved everything to a staging site and imported the sql DB, and the error remains. This means that somewhere on the database something is trying to autoload a plugin that doesn't exist anymore. Any ideas on how I could find what is calling this?
